# How to configure data and pass to the test file

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I would like configure all the input data in a file and would like my test read the data from that file while running test. For example, in the below I would like to configure browsername, search parameter, server address in a file.

Below is my test:

```
var driver = require("selenium-webdriver");
driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    usingServer(server.address()).
    withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome'}).
    build();

it('should append query to title', function() {
        driver.get('http://www.google.com');
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
        driver.wait(function() {
            return driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
                return 'webdriver - Google Search' === title;
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Basically I want to know how to run same test file with different data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a json file with all the configuration options, and iterate over them.

```
{
"config": [
    {
        "browser":"Firefox",
        "searchParameter":"parameter",
        "serverAddress":"127.0.0.1"
    },
    {
        "browser":"Chrome",
        "searchParameter":"parameter",
        "serverAddress":"127.0.0.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, create a loop, and repeat the test as many options are in the file.

Comment: Thanks.Is this the standard way of doing in production?